# First Order ODE find general solution and plot

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

After substituting y=1.01 and x=0, i have  $$\frac{-1}{y-1} =x-100$$

For C1=0.01 and C2=0, my general solution is $$10tan^{-1}(10(y-1)) =x+C$$ After substituting y=1 and x=0, i have $$10tan^{-1}(10(y-1)) =x$$

Comment: Your general solution doesn't satisfy the ODE. Try separating variables and making the substitution $y - 1 = \sqrt{C_{1}} \tan \theta$.

Comment: I dont get it, what is the relation of  y−1=C1−−√tanθ

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. Separate the variables i.e $$\frac{dy}{C_{1} + (y-1)^{2}} = dx$$ Then, when you go to integrate, the integral in $y$ can be solved by making the substitution $y - 1 = \sqrt{C_{1}} \tan \theta$. The general solution is then given by $$y = \sqrt{C_{1}} \tan(\sqrt{C_{1}}(x+A)) + 1$$ for arbitrary constants $A$ and $C_{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

@Jean Low : The general solution ( any $C_1$ , $C_2$ ) is missing in your answer. In fact, there is no need for it to answer to the three cases of different conditions.

In the particular cases of $C_1$ , $C_2$ , see below :

It should be better to give the solutions on the form $y(x)$ instead of $x(y)$ in order to compare the three cases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$y'(x)=\left(y(x)-1\right)^2+\text{K}\Longleftrightarrow\int\frac{y'(x)}{\left(y(x)-1\right)^2+\text{K}}\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x$$

Use:

1. Substitute $u=y(x)-1$ and $\text{d}u=y'(x)\space\text{d}x$ after that substitute $s=\frac{u}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}$ and $\text{d}s=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}\space\text{d}u$:
   $$\int\frac{y'(x)}{\left(y(x)-1\right)^2+\text{K}}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{u^2+\text{K}}\space\text{d}u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}\int\frac{1}{1+s^2}\space\text{d}s=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{y(x)-1}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}+\text{C}$$
2. $$\int1\space\text{d}x=x+\text{C}$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{y(x)-1}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}=x+\text{C}$$

---

Assuming that $y(\text{a})=\text{b}$ (when $\sqrt{\text{K}}\ne0$):

$$\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\text{b}-1}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}=\text{a}+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow\text{C}=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\text{b}-1}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}-\text{a}$$

So:

$$\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{y(x)-1}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}=x+\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\text{b}-1}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}-\text{a}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=1-\sqrt{\text{K}}\tan\left\{\sqrt{\text{K}}\left(\text{a}-x\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\text{b}-1}{\sqrt{\text{K}}}\right)\right\}$$